# Errors when I split a string

Tags: c#, string, split

when I try to split some strings, I got two type of errors:

```
Error   1   The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments
Error   2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'
```

This is my part of code about that:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(data_odd))
{
    if (node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains(("first-cell")))
        rowBet.Match = node.InnerText.Trim();
    var matchTeam = rowBet.Match.Split("-", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    rowBet.Home = matchTeam[0];
    rowBet.Host = matchTeam[1];

    if (node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains(("result")))
        rowBet.Result = node.InnerText.Trim();
    var matchPoints = rowBet.Result.Split(":", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    rowBet.HomePoints = int.Parse(matchPoints[0];
    rowBet.HostPoints = int.Parse(matchPoints[1];

    if (node.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Contains(("last-cell")))
        rowBet.Date = node.InnerText.Trim();
}
```

I really don't know how I can fix it. I hope you can help me.

EDIT: Homepoints and Hostpoints are declared int in my bet class.

Comment: `var matchPoints = rowBet.Result.Split(":".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);`

Comment: yes, "-" represents a string not a character, change it to single quotes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass the seperator as a character, not as a string (with single quotation marks)

```
var matchTeam = rowBet.Match.Split("-".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: @user Why did you remove the `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`?

Comment: @PatrickHofman because the original code and your modification don't compile .Edited to include it.

Comment: @dotctor What are you doing, this doesn't compile !

Comment: Then let zockDoc change the code. You change the meaning of the answer. *His* answer, not yours!

Comment: Sorry I have to correct myself, homepoints and hostpoints are int so I got an error just in the second case. Can you suggest me the right correction, please? Thanks :)

Comment: I'm sorry, your right, if I want to Keep the StringSplitOptions I have to pass a char array.

Comment: Now your answer is just a copy of the answer of dotctor, I don't think there is much use to it.

Comment: @Marci Then you just have to parse the parts to integers
`int.Parse(matchPoints[0])`

Comment: ok, I edited my code in my post, is it correct now?

Comment: Well, you forgot to close the brackets of the parse method and of course there is still the error in the split Syntax but except for that it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a string to `char[]` by using [`ToCharArray()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var matchTeam = rowBet.Match.Split("-".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var matchPoints = rowBet.Result.Split(":".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Or generate an array on the fly!

```
var matchTeam = rowBet.Match.Split(new char[] { '-' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
var matchPoints = rowBet.Result.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
```

Comment: Sorry I have to correct myself, homepoints and hostpoints are int so I got an error just in the second case. Can you suggest me the right correction, please? Thanks :)